# Apache HttpClient Wire Logs to JSON

Tags: java, spring, logback, slf4j

I'm new to SLF4J and Logback and I'm trying to log every HTTP request and response in a Json format.
Here's the configuration:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ReportPortalAppender" class="com.epam.reportportal.logback.appender.ReportPortalAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
</appender>

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="ReportPortalAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>

<logger name="org.apache.http.wire">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

Currently, it's printing:

```
16:56:44.840 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "GET /version HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.845 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Accept: application/json, application/javascript, text/javascript[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.845 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Host: localhost:4243[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.845 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.845 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.873 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.874 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Api-Version: 1.41[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.874 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.874 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Date: Wed, 28 Dec 2022 14:56:44 GMT[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.874 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Docker-Experimental: false[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.874 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Ostype: linux[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.875 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Server: Docker/20.10.21 (linux)[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.875 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.875 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "33c[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "{"Platform":{"Name":"Docker Desktop 4.15.0 (93002)"},"Components":[{"Name":"Engine","Version":"20.10.21","Details":{"ApiVersion":"1.41","Arch":"amd64","BuildTime":"2022-10-25T18:00:19.000000000+00:00","Experimental":"false","GitCommit":"3056208","GoVersion":"go1.18.7","KernelVersion":"5.15.49-linuxkit","MinAPIVersion":"1.12","Os":"linux"}},{"Name":"containerd","Version":"1.6.10","Details":{"GitCommit":"770bd0108c32f3fb5c73ae1264f7e503fe7b2661"}},{"Name":"runc","Version":"1.1.4","Details":{"GitCommit":"v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d"}},{"Name":"docker-init","Version":"0.19.0","Details":{"GitCommit":"de40ad0"}}],"Version":"20.10.21","ApiVersion":"1.41","MinAPIVersion":"1.12","GitCommit":"3056208","GoVersion":"go1.18.7","Os":"linux","Arch":"amd64","KernelVersion":"5.15.49-linuxkit","BuildTime":"2022-10-25T18:00:19.000000000+00:00"}[\n]"
16:56:44.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "0[\r][\n]"
16:56:44.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
```

And I want to log something like:

```
{
    "url": "GET /version HTTP/1.1",
    "status": 200,
    "elapsed_time": 2630 ,
    "response": {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2"
    }
}
```

I am using IntelliJ Idea, running on macOS (latest).

Comment: As @hiran-chaudhuri stated the log format coming from `org.apache.http.wire` is dictated by how that class is programmed.  A possible way to get around this is to extend the Wire class and give your own implementation of how you want things printed out to your log file.  That being said, I don't think that it would be easy and It would take some digging to figure out how to get HttpClient to use your class instead of their default class.

Answer (score 0):

The category org.apache.http.wire is written by Apache httpclient automatically. The log you want will likely not be produced by httpclient and thus not achievable with just logging configuration.

You will have to add such logging to your application, at which point you have full control over the log output.

Running IntelliJ on MacOS is not relevant in this case.